# Prime with a given digit sum

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $n>1$ is not divisible by 3. Is there a prime such that the sum of its decimal digits is equal to $n$?

More generally, given a base $b\ge2$ and $n>1$ coprime to $b-1$, is there a prime such that the sum of its base-$b$ digits is equal to $n$?

At first glance this seems like an obviously true but hopeless to prove statements. But work in the last decade by such authors as Drmota, Martin, Mauduit, Rivat, and Sárközy** makes it seem plausible that the result is known.

Trivial results: $n=2$ works, choosing 2 in any base. $n=3$ works choosing 3 in bases above 3 and 7 otherwise. The smallest nonobvious case is $n=4$ which I have checked in even bases up to $10^6.$ Larger numbers should only get easier in terms of degrees of freedom.

Perhaps the problem is more obvious than it seems, any ideas?

** Note: There's always a risk of leaving someone off a list of authors. To guard against possible offense I deleted one or two authors at random from my original list. Now as long as I haven't missed three prominent names I should be OK...!

Comment: This is kind of opposite of what you asked, given any $n$ and $m$, there exists a $k$ such that, $S_b(kn)=mn$. $S_b$ is sum of digit function in base $b$.

Answer (score 0):

One might note that if the sum is to be something like $4$ of $6$, then there are bases where every number except $1$ is already co-composite with the base.  For example, with in base 120, the numbers 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 already divide the base, so one is looking for numbers like 5.01, 1.04.01, 2.03.01, 3.02.01, 4.01.01, 5.00.01, etc.

If one excludes the existance of the number itself (ie it must be a proper sum), then the search is rather harder.  For example, in base 64, there are no instances of $64^x+1$ which leads to a prime number.  All of these have algebraic factors.

But it seems that if a series has an indicated co-primeness, then a prime turns up sooner or later, sometimes much later.

Comment: What do you mean by "4 of 6"?

Comment: As to your second paragraph, clearly 2 (and possibly 3) would be too hard without allowing the number itself. But is there a problem with larger numbers?

Comment: 4 of 6 ought be '4 or 6'.  Also, if $b$ is a proper odd power (ie that it's not $b^{2^n}$), then $b^x+1$ is never prime if $x\gt 0$.

Comment: 4 of 6 ought be '4 or 6'.  The issue i was trying to allude to was corrected in the balance of the para.  With the second para, one can show that if $b$ is an odd power of some number (ie $b=a^{2x+1}$ where $x\gt 0$), then it is relatively easy to show that the only solution of $b^n+1$ is prime only for $n=0$. But for $3$ and greater, one can see eg that 111, 1011 and 1101 are prime in binary and base three.

Comment: But $b^n+1$ is only relevant if $n=2,$ right?